# How to access contract attributes?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have initialized my contract and need to balanceOf the current logged in address

```
const contract = new web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);

  contract.balanceOf(function (error, balance) {
        $('account-balance').html = balance;
     });
```

but now i have troubles accessing the functions within the contract.

I get this error for trying to get "balanceOf"

```
inpage.js:1 Uncaught Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
    at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs (inpage.js:1)
    at u.validateArgs (inpage.js:1)
    at u.toPayload (inpage.js:1)
    at u.call (inpage.js:1)
    at u.execute (inpage.js:1)
    at exchange.js:59
```

Comment: You should pass to function `balanceOf` the account whose balance you seek to get.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: i need the balance of the current logged-in address

Answer (score 0):

First get all the accounts:

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

Then get balance of the first one, for example:

```
const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
```

BTW: I used "await" in the example above, thus your function has to be an async one, e.g.

```
async function getUserBalance() {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
}
```

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#getbalance

Comment: i dont need the balance from web3.eth - i need the token balance "balanceOf" the current logged in user/account.
Please look at this code https://pastebin.com/H29q9px6

Comment: Sorry. Misunderstood.

Does your solidity token contract have a "balanceOf" function? If yes: Check, what inputs this function expects. Should only be an address as @goodvibrations already wrote. If you found it use `const nToken = await contract.methods.balanceOf(<user-address>).call();`

Comment: contract.balanceOf('0x62f28320f688A7A4e0021c55d7ffD1acd770A133', function ( error) {
        $('#account-balance').html = balance;
     });
this gives me a eth_call is not a function error

Comment: i should be able to pass in the accounts variable but neither works accounts variable nor the address itself. when pastin in accounts- it says accounts not defined- but i use the accounts variable further up in the code. SO i dont know whats the issue here https://pastebin.com/wAsCeNTG

Comment: Can we see your Solidity code? The ABI alone is a bit hard (at least for me).

Comment: sure here is the contract on ropsten
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xe462cbee0cd420f6c199b0194b1d8d93fb5e7720#code

Answer (score 0):

Just for for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="account-address"></div>
  <div id="number-of-token"></div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.37/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    const address = '0xE462CbEE0cd420f6c199B0194B1D8D93Fb5e7720';
    const abi = [{ "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_customerAddress", "type": "address" }], "name": "dividendsOf", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "name", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "string" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_agiToSpend", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "calculateTokensReceived", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_tokensToSell", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "calculateAgiReceived", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "totalSupply", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "onlyAmbassadors", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "decimals", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint8" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_customerAddress", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_referredBy", "type": "address" }], "name": "buyFor", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "withdraw", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "sellPrice", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "stakingRequirement", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_includeReferralBonus", "type": "bool" }], "name": "myDividends", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [{ "name": "_customerAddress", "type": "address" }], "name": "balanceOf", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "_referredBy", "type": "address" }], "name": "buy", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "buyPrice", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "owner", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "address" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "distribute", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "myTokens", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "symbol", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "string" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_toAddress", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_amountOfTokens", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transfer", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_symbol", "type": "string" }], "name": "setSymbol", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "getInvested", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_name", "type": "string" }], "name": "setName", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "totalAgiBalance", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "maintenance", "type": "address" }], "name": "updateMaintenanceAddress2", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "maintenance", "type": "address" }], "name": "updateMaintenanceAddress1", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "_amountOfTokens", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "sell", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "exit", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "totalDonation", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "totalHolder", "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "newOwner", "type": "address" }], "name": "transferOwnership", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "reinvest", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "constructor" }, { "payable": true, "stateMutability": "payable", "type": "fallback" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "customerAddress", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "price", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "onDistribute", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "customerAddress", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "incomingAGI", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "tokensMinted", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "referredBy", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "timestamp", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "onTokenPurchase", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "customerAddress", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "tokensBurned", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "agiEarned", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "timestamp", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "onTokenSell", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "customerAddress", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "agiReinvested", "type": "uint256" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "tokensMinted", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "onReinvestment", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "customerAddress", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "agiWithdrawn", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "onWithdraw", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "tokens", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "Transfer", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "name": "previousOwner", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "newOwner", "type": "address" }], "name": "OwnershipTransferred", "type": "event" }];
    window.addEventListener('load', async function () {
      // Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 injection timing.
      if (window.ethereum) {
        console.log(1);
        window.web3 = new Web3(window['ethereum']);
        try {
          // Request account access if needed
          await window.ethereum.enable();
          getUserBalance();
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      } else if (window.web3) {
        console.log(2);
        // Legacy dapp browsers...
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
        window.web3 = window.web3;
        console.log('Injected web3 detected.');
      } else {
        console.log(3);
        // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
        const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/9bee77f147884c73bb2852e269dacece');
        window.web3 = new Web3(provider);
        console.log('No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.');
      }
    });

    async function getUserBalance() {
      const web3 = window.web3;
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts(); //This is an array of all accounts. Usually you want the first one ([0]).
      document.getElementById('account-address').innerHTML = accounts[0];

      const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address); //Load contract
      const nToken = await contract.methods.balanceOf(accounts[0]).call(); //With call() you are just reading blockchain data
      document.getElementById('number-of-token').innerHTML = nToken;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i dont know, its not printing anything and i cant access any of that stuff in there

Comment: i cant access accounts and i cant access nToken

Comment: Updated my answer. I think you already have a good understanding of the basics. Nonetheless I would propose a web development crash course (HTML, CSS, JS) - possibly from "Traversy Media" or "Net Ninja" on YouTube. Once you feel more or less comfortable check out the YouTube channel "dApp University" for Ethereum dApp development.

Comment: none of these courses cover UIs. I dont like none of their tutorials